How do I fix the positioning of the page on orientation change in android for .net MAUI?
I have a .NET MAUI application that was working for fine for android when the orientation changes from portrait to landscape. However, after some packages for the project were upgraded, I now have a weird black void on the left side of the screen when the orientation has been changed to landscape. As if the whole screen shifted by a few pixels to the right. (Note: I am referring to the whole PAGE object itself, not any XAML element in the layout.) I do wonder if this problem can be solved without the need to revert the packages though.
Edit: Here is an image of the issue that I am having:
]1
I tried removing some code that I thought would be the culprit at the top of certain XAML pages in the ContentPage.Behaviors tags:
<ContentPage.Behaviors> <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="#4085c0" StatusBarStyle="LightStyle" /> </ContentPage.Behaviors>
However, that did not work. (It was a shot in the dark anyway.) I also double-checked the android code for my orientation service as seen below:
public enum DeviceOrientation
{
    Undefined,
    Landscape,
    Portrait
}

//...

public class DeviceOrientationService : IDeviceOrientationService
{
#if IOS
//...
#elif ANDROID
        public DeviceOrientation GetOrientation() 
        {
            var getDeviceCurrentActivity = ActivityStateManager.Default.GetCurrentActivity();
            var orientation = getDeviceCurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation;

            if (orientation == Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape)
            {
                return DeviceOrientation.Landscape;
            }
            return DeviceOrientation.Portrait;
        }
#endif
//..
        public void SetOrientation(DeviceOrientation orientation)
        {
#if ANDROID
            var getDeviceCurrentActivity = ActivityStateManager.Default.GetCurrentActivity();

            if (orientation == DeviceOrientation.Landscape)
            {
                getDeviceCurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
            }
            else
            {
                getDeviceCurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            }
#elif IOS
//..
#endif
        }
    }
}

However, I could not find anything wrong. I also did a good amount of research online and I couldn't find anything related to the problem that I am having. If anyone else has ran into this problem, any help on this issue would be great. Thanks!

What does the issue look like? What have you tried to isolate the issue? You're mentioning that some packages have been upgraded, have you tried reverting those changes and then upgrade each package one-by-one to see which one is the culprit?

Hi Julian, I do apologize for the lack of clarity. I will provide an image here in a little while. As far as the packages go, I am not sure what versions were implemented before, unfortunately since they were not upgraded by me, but by a coworker. I think I can figure this out by looking at the .csproj right? I'll just do that then and get back to you.

Aren't you using a version control system? Just look in the history and see which versions have been used before. Yes, you can see the current versions in the .csproj file.

Hi Julian sorry for the dumb question xD. I just wanted to be sure.  I am going through the history now and it looks like I found the packages that are the culprits. Will let you know when I have an update. I also provided you an image of the issue that I am having in the updated question.

Well, I reverted the Maui.Controls package, and Maui.Controls.Compatability back to version 8.0.14 from 8.0.21, and this still appears to be an issue. I also did a clean and rebuild of the solution and double checked the history on the .csproj file, and I didn't notice anymore packages that changed, and this is still happening. Again, this only happens on orientation changing.

Does this happen on a real device or just in the emulator?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
